# Accidentally deleted windows partition, how can I do a factory reset with only Ubuntu working to restore windows?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

While installing Ubuntu, I made a tactical error of my laptop turning off during the Partitioning of my hard drive (manual).

Okay, so in my Grub loader i have Ubuntu (12.04) (works just fine) , ubuntu recovery, memeory test, Windows 7 (immediatly goes to an error/not found screen), and windows 7 recovery.

When I go into windows 7 recovery, and click to do a system restore to factory reset, you must restart the system to initiate. But, It just restarts to GRUB menu.

I have an HP Pavilion dm4-2015dx

My end goal is to do a factory reset, and re-install Ubuntu so I can properly dual boot both OS's.

I dont have a windows 7 disk laying around, and I dont have any backed up images of my hardrive prior to the accident.

Any ideas to how I can get windows back on my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

If the Windows recovery worked, you should be able to just change a GRUB boot menu to get it to boot. You may also just have to select the windows recovery partition again if it is still in the middle of recovering.

Assuming it worked, but GRUB is not working for whatever reason, you can try using qemu-kvm in Ubuntu to emulate booting off of a partition of your hard drive and test it. For example:

```
sudo kvm /dev/sda2
```

You'll need to use the following to determine which partition it is:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

If the Windows recovery does not work, you can look into [system rescue cd](http://www.sysresccd.org/Download), a linux distro built for data/system recovery (note that this is mainly for recovering data from a damaged partition that you can't just copy over from Ubuntu; if you are able, it would be easier to do the latter). After recovering your data, you can download a windows 7 install disk from one of the links below and then install windows onto that partition and copy your data over:

- [Home Premium (x64)](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-58997.iso)
- [Professional (x64)](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59186.iso)
- [Ultimate (x64)](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59465.iso)
- [Home Premium (i386)](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-58996.iso)
- [Professional (i386)](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59183.iso)
- [Ultimate (i386)](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59463.iso)

Your product key should be on your computer somewhere if it came with windows.

**TL;DR**

1. See if the install actually did work, but GRUB is just getting in
   the way or not working
2. If not, recover what you can and install Windows again.